# Choose install path for ClickOnce application during setup

Tags: c#, .net, oneclick

Can I ask the user WHERE to install the application during install time?
Most setups prompt the user where to install the application, I'm sure you are familiar with it. How can I do this with the visual studio publisher? (If it cannot be done from the VS publisher could you reccommend a program that can do it? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: The only reason I would use clickonce was to use automatic update feature, but ahh it does not let you choose install path, a bit wierd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/84b5ed72-2406-4518-97e7-f7c6cf7132a7) MSDN post: "ClickOnce application are installed per user in the user application cache. These applications are managed by the ClickOnce service. If you want to install to a user specifed location such a Program Files... you should use MSI or some other installer technology."

The other deployment methodologies supported by Visual Studio are discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.  ClickOnce install the application in a user's AppData folder it's not installed like a traditional application.  If you want to have more control over stuff like this you need to write your own installer.

Comment: prompting the user for an installation location is the default behavior of the setup project - no need to write an installer if he's using visual studio

Comment: @JimMcKeon That was probably poorly worded, by the point I was trying to convey was that he would need to use a different installer technology.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is changed, but ClickOnce applications are installed per user in the user application cache. You cant change that location. This means that if 2 different user share the same machine there are 2 different copies of your application.