# how to set install path for a visual studio program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i cannot find anything online but i need to set up the install path for my c sharp winform visual studio program. when i install it it just goes to appdata and then has a million random numbers and letters. the issue is everytime i install this it has different letters and numbers so i always have a new path to allow a program through on my antivirus across multiple computers. how to i set the install path so it will install with the same path everytime?

Comment: How are you installing the application? ClickOnce?

Comment: @gunr2171 i just publish the program and then it gives me setup and application files. i then run the setup to install the program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose install path for ClickOnce application during setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209427/choose-install-path-for-clickonce-application-during-setup)

Comment: Publish has a setup.exe which is a self extracting zip file.  So just make sure you run the setup.exe it is the same path on every computer.

Comment: @jdweng this is not true it does  not install as the same file path. it makes some random letters and numbers and it is never the same.

Comment: Then you must be installing in the user TEMP area, or the folder already exists.  An installation is never random.

Comment: If you're using ClickOnce, this doesn't seem to be possible because ClickOnce applications are installed per user in the user application cache. You cannot change this location. Other than that, the [default location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028287/20376806) seems to help you